# internet explorer 11 prevent popup or warning messages

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, warnings, activex

I am having difficulty to prevent popup messages and warning ActiveX message.

[image]

[image]

I have javascript code that will run on client-side, and will depend on ActiveX to call `DLL` file in order to print a receipt. I do not want my customer to click on any buttons related to messages warning or printer dialog boxes, since this a specific web application designed specially for one customer.

Please, any help to prevent Internet Explorer 11 to show these security messages.

Note: I had changed the `Custom Level` for security regarding ActiveX, and turned off the pop-up blocker under privacy, but the messages in the images I posted still appear.

Comment: If people could just turn off security warnings in other's browser, we would face a huge problem...

Comment: In internet options, advanced, Under Security, check: Allow Active Content to run ...

Comment: @Skwal How can I disable this warning anyway? i have a same trouble, using activeX in IE11 for local project. I get data from the registry and check files for existence using ActiveX.